# Why ".post p:first-child" doesn't select what I want from my HTML code (article)?

Tags: html, css

My HTML Code:

```
<article class="post" id="first">
   <header>
   <h1>Title</h1>
   </header>
 <p>First paragraph</p>
 <p>Second paragraph</p>
   <footer>
 <p>This is a footer</p>
   </footer>
</article>
```

My CSS code:

```
.post p:first-child {color: green;}
```

I can't understand why this paragraph stays green : `<p>This is a footer</p>` instead of this one: `<p>First paragraph</p>` since this is the first element child `<p>` of the class `.post`

Can you explain me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The p tag is not the "first-child" of the article tag, the header tag is. You are looking for `first-of-type` attribute selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you do no have a direct descendent selector (`>`) it will select any first-child of any descendant of `.post`.

To get the result you want, you must write `.post > p:first-of-type`, which will select the first direct child element `p` to appear in `.post`.

```css
.post > p:first-of-type { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<article class="post" id="first">
 <header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
 </header>
 <p>First paragraph</p>
 <p>Second paragraph</p>
 <footer>
  <p>This is a footer</p>
 </footer>
</article>
```